# div overlap another though position of div is relative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I have a chart made using d3.js : [code for chart](https://jsfiddle.net/qp7L1hob/)

I am trying to put this chart within a website.[website](http://79.170.44.120/shivams.com/)

Problem is that one div overflows the other as can be seen in the website.
I tried changing the position of the chart to relative from absolute.It doesnot work.

What may be the issue.Why is this happening ?Any idea.

fiddle related to the website :[My code so far](https://jsfiddle.net/jn1ba77s/) (experiment here)

css and  d3 javascript Code for the chart as used in the website ( everything is available in above fiddle link) :

```js
'use strict';

var dataset = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];

// let colors = ['#8dd3c7', '#ffffb3', '#bebada', '#fb8072', '#80b1d3', '#fdb462', '#b3de69', '#fccde5', '#d9d9d9', '#bc80bd'];
let colors = ['#67001f', '#b2182b', '#d6604d', '#f4a582', '#fddbc7', '#e0e0e0', '#bababa', '#878787', '#4d4d4d', '#1a1a1a', 'white', 'white'];
var months = ['January - 2016', 'February - 2016', 'March - 2016', 'April - 2016', 'May - 2016', 'June - 2016', 'July - 2016', 'August - 2016', 'September - 2016', 'October - 2016', 'November - 2016', 'December - 2016'];
var dataWeeks = ["Week 1: 32<br>Week 2: 54<br>Week 3: 19<br>Week 4: 12", "Week 5: 22<br>Week 6: 14<br>Week 7: 12<br>Week 8: 03<br>Week 9:44", "Week 10: 14<br>Week 11: 11<br>Week 12: 23<br>Week 13:20 <br>Quarter 1 :25", "Week 14: 53<br>Week 15: 16<br>Week 16: 11 <br>Week 17:33", "Week 18: 52<br>Week 19: 22<br>Week 20: 12 <br>Week 21 :09 <br>Week 22:34", "Week 23: 59<br>Week 24: 87 <br>Week 25:36<br>Week 26:78<br>Quarter 2 :56<br>Half Yearly 1 :98", "Week 27: 69<br>Week 28: 33<br>Week 29: 11<br>Week 30: 65", "Week 31: 69<br>Week 32: 33<br>Week 33: 99<br>Week 34: 66<br>Week 35: 19", "Week 36: 84<br>Week 37: 16<br>Week 38: 66<br>Week 39: 11<br>Quarter 3 : 77", "Week 40: 86<br>Week 41: 21<br>Week 42: 52<br>Week 43: 12<br>Week 44: 37", "Week 45: 90<br>Week 46: 69<br>Week 47: 19<br>Week 48: 17", "Week 49:33 <br>Week 50:09 <br>Week 51:44 <br>Week 52 : 89<br>Quarter 4 :66<br>Half Yearly 2:99"];

var width = document.querySelector('.chart-wrapper').offsetWidth,
  height = document.querySelector('.chart-wrapper').offsetHeight,
  minOfWH = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
  initialAnimDelay = 300,
  arcAnimDelay = 150,
  arcAnimDur = 3000,
  secDur = 1000,
  secIndividualdelay = 150;

var radius = undefined;

// calculate minimum of width and height to set chart radius
if (minOfWH > 200) {
  radius = 200;
} else {
  radius = minOfWH;
}

// append svg
var svg = d3.select('.chart-wrapper').append('svg').attr({
  'width': width,
  'height': height,
  'class': 'pieChart'
}).append('g');

svg.attr({
  'transform': 'translate(' + width / 2 + ', ' + height / 2 + ')'
});

// for drawing slices
var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius * 0.6).innerRadius(radius * 0.45);

// for labels and polylines
var outerArc = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(radius * 0.85).outerRadius(radius * 0.85);

// d3 color generator
// let c10 = d3.scale.category10();

var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "tooltip").style("opacity", 0);

var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d) {
  return d;
});

var draw = function draw() {

  svg.append("g").attr("class", "lines");
  svg.append("g").attr("class", "slices");
  svg.append("g").attr("class", "labels");

  // define slice
  var slice = svg.select('.slices').datum(dataset).selectAll('path').data(pie);
  slice.enter().append('path').attr({
    'fill': function fill(d, i) {
      return colors[i];
    },
    'd': arc,
    'stroke-width': '25px'
  }).attr('transform', function(d, i) {
    return 'rotate(-180, 0, 0)';
  }).style('opacity', 0).transition().delay(function(d, i) {
    return i * arcAnimDelay + initialAnimDelay;
  }).duration(arcAnimDur).ease('elastic').style('opacity', 1).attr('transform', 'rotate(0,0,0)');

  slice.transition().delay(function(d, i) {
    return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
  }).duration(secDur).attr('stroke-width', '5px');

  var midAngle = function midAngle(d) {
    return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
  };

  var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text").data(pie(dataset));

  text.enter().append('text').attr('dy', '0.35em').style("opacity", 0).attr("cursor", "default").style('fill', function(d, i) {
    return colors[i];
  }).text(function(d, i) {
    return months[i];
  }).attr('transform', function(d) {
    // calculate outerArc centroid for 'this' slice
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    // define left and right alignment of text labels
    pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return 'translate(' + pos + ')';
  }).style('text-anchor', function(d) {
    return midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? "start" : "end";
  }).transition().delay(function(d, i) {
    return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
  }).duration(secDur).style('opacity', 1);

  text.on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
    tooltip.html(dataWeeks[i])
      .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 6 + 'px')
      .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 14 + 'px')
      .style("opacity", 1);
  }).on("mouseout", function(d) {
    tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
  });


  var polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline").data(pie(dataset));

  polyline.enter().append("polyline").style("opacity", 0.5).attr('points', function(d) {
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return [arc.centroid(d), arc.centroid(d), arc.centroid(d)];
  }).transition().duration(secDur).delay(function(d, i) {
    return arcAnimDur + i * secIndividualdelay;
  }).attr('points', function(d) {
    var pos = outerArc.centroid(d);
    pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
    return [arc.centroid(d), outerArc.centroid(d), pos];
  });
};

draw();

var button = document.querySelector('button');

var replay = function replay() {

  d3.selectAll('.slices').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(0).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();
  d3.selectAll('.lines').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(100).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();
  d3.selectAll('.labels').transition().ease('back').duration(500).delay(200).style('opacity', 0).attr('transform', 'translate(0, 250)').remove();

  setTimeout(draw, 800);
};
```

```css
.chart-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
  position: relative;
}
path {
  stroke: #0d0d0d;
  /* stroke-width: 5px; */
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: fill 250ms;
  transition: fill 250ms;
}
path:hover {
  /* stroke-width: 10px; */
  fill: #fff;
}
text {
  font-size: .8em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
}
polyline {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-dasharray: 5px;
}
button {
  position: realtive;
  top: 20px;
  left: 820px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: .6em;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  -webkit-transition: all 250ms;
  transition: all 250ms;
}
button:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #0d0d0d;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff;
}
button:active {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
div.tooltip {
  position: realtive;
  padding: 4px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: did you try giving relative position to the container ?

Comment: @CodeBean tried doing .but no luck.Thanks.

Comment: did you refreshed your browser cache or any other cache after setting the relative position?

Comment: yeah always... @sheetal Thanks.

Comment: it goes alright when set to relative position in browser...i guess css is getting overrided, try adding !important to the position style..did you tried it before?

Comment: @sheetal thanks for the input.Its not helping.no luck yet. this is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/jn1ba77s/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the position css attribute entirely from the chart-wrapper

```
.chart-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0d0d0d;
}
```

and edit the parent of chart-wrapper and add custom height. You can tune the height to make it fit correctly.

```
<div class="container" style="height:700px;">
```

I tested the same on your site via Chrome dev tools css manager. It no longer overlaps and sits properly.

Comment: @TeRml thanks fr the input.I tried doing what you just sai.Its not helping.Plz see here :https://jsfiddle.net/jn1ba77s/3/

Comment: Sorry but the jsfiddle isn't working for me. All the image links are broken and the js widget isn't loading.

Comment: I think its a problem with the fiddle. Just make the change on the site. You should see the expected result. You can just play around with my suggested css in chrome-dev-tools to see if it works, its much easier to work with compared to jsfiddle.

Comment: Yeah.I understand.but its not working locally too.when i change the position,or remove the position and then load the code in the server,it doesnot work.plz ignore the image in the fiddle.That I can fix just by giving some link to some images,bt not doing as its not the issue here.Anyways,thanks for trying.God bless

Comment: Looks like your browser is caching old css files. Just do a hard reload by deleting cached files. You can use ctrl+shift+del to clear cache. Just be careful not to delete any saved passwords or filled fields

Comment: okay.But this is what happens when i remove the position , http://79.170.44.120/shivams.com/

Comment: @jane - The problem is that everyone seems to be trying to solve this in the browser console, but the SVG is created dynamically and isn't there on pageload. You set the width and height of the SVG based on the parent `.chart-wrapper`, but when that element doesn't specifically have `position: absolute` on first pageload, it has no height, so it doesn't work. The thing is, it of course works when you change the values in the browser console, after the SVG is generated, but won't work on your site.

Comment: @adeneo this seems to be an issue I am alien to.I read ur comment twice.It would be very kind of u,if u help me solve this.Thanks.god bless.

Comment: that means if you give the manual height in px to the .chart-wrapper instead of 100% it would work

Comment: Yeah I agree with adeneo. Removing absolute only solves part of the problem. You have to change the available height of the chart-wrapper div.

Comment: Awesome.I figured out.It works fine now .Thanks a lot everyone.God bless.

Comment: i didnot go for inline .m sure it will work as well @TeRmI thanks .

Answer (score -1):

You have to remove the "*position: absolute;*" Of the "**.chart-wrapper**"

Comment: as said in the question.I have already tried doing so.This fiddle link will tell u that change the position to realtive isnot working : https://jsfiddle.net/jn1ba77s/      Anyways thanks for the input @D.Fraga